# FAILED (remote: (InvalidState)) while installing android L on Nexus 7

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm trying the flash the android-L developer preview on my Nexus 7.
I've downloaded the file from google developer and followed instructions.
When in bootloader, and running the the "flash-all" script from terminal, I'm getting the following:

```
writing 'bootloader'...
FAILED (remote: (InvalidState))
finished. total time: 0.752s
```

found one [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=73835) that was opened for google, on the wrong place and didn't find it on the current open issues.

Anyone encountered the same error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad.
In my case that error occurred because I didn't payed attention and tried to install the version on my Nexus 7 2012 device.
The developer preview of L is only valid for the 2013 model.